# django session lost when redirected from facebook oauth

Tags: django, facebook, session, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have a django app which is implementing Facebook oauth login.

Before an AnonymousUser, who has not yet been authenticated, is sent to Facebook's oauth2, I store a token in the request.session.

Once the user log's in via facebook and is redirected back to our site, the django session is lost. A new session key has been generated, the old session key is removed from the db session store, and there is no data in the session (so the original session token is missing). I can't figure out why this is happening and need to get the original token?

I have the following in settings.py

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.mysite.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
```

Comment: For debuuging try changing `SESSION_ENGINE` to `"django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"`. Does this resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Session cookie has to be set to false. If it is true, you can only store session cookies in an https connection, and I assume your testing environment does not use https